# What does the word ''root'' really mean?

Tags: terminology, definition, roots

So I have been asked this question:

> Suppose $$\theta = 0.5\pi + \sin(\theta).$$
> Verify by calculation that $\theta$ lies between $2.2$ and $2.4.$

What my book has done is put all the terms on the left-hand site and replace the $0$ on the right-hand side with $f(\theta)$.

My question is, why am I not asked to find the root of $\theta$? Why am I asked to find $\theta$? And from the function what happens with the $0$?

Comment: a root of a function can mean a zero of the function, i.e., $\theta$ such that $f(\theta)=0$

Comment: The word "root" has multiple meanings in mathematics, which can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_(disambiguation)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you mean? : https://www.deviantart.com/onrainyafternoons16/art/Root-871920192?ga_submit_new=10%3A1614627750

Answer (score 0):

"Roots" refer to the values that make a polynomial equal to zero.  For example, if $p(x)=x^2-2x+1$ is your polynomial, then to find the roots you set up the equation $x^2-2x+1=0$ and find values of $x$ that solve it.

If you have a pre-existing equation, you don't call solutions to it "roots."

Roots of polynomials are important because they have to do with factoring.  In the above polynomial, $x=1$ is a root, and with some more work we can factor it as $(x-1)^2$.

(Note: it's reasonably common to talk about roots of a function as well, but at least in my experience it's more common for non-polynomial functions to call them "zeros.")